# How to only find a substring in a string?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a large strings on my php page.

I need to find a small part of this large string.

For example the large string looks like this:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
>   scrambled it to make a type specimen _ Document Number : 4575 - NIA -
>   000 book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
>   into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
>   popularised in the 1960s with the release Date: 2016 - 03 - 04 of
>   Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
>   with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
>   versions of Lorem Ipsum.

So, what I need to find and display in my php page is the `Document Number : 4575 - NIA - 000` and the `Date: 2016 - 03 - 04`.

I tried something like this:

```
$date = substr($result, 0, strpos($result, 'Date:'));
echo $date;
```

But this doesn't produce the required output on my php page.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex.

This pattern will find what you need.
Since it's a very long regex I'm not going to explain it in detail, but you can easily find information about how regex work.

```
preg_match_all("/Document\s+Number\s*:\s*(.*?\s*-.*?\s*-\s*.*?)\s|Date\s*:\s*(\d{4}\s*-\s*\d{2}\s*-\s*\d{2})/i", $str, $matches);
```

But in short, it will look for patterns and capture the needed part of the string.
`\s*` or `\s+` is space, either optional (*) or a requirement but unlimited allowed (+).
`\d` is digit. `\d+` will be any length of digits. `\d{4}` is four digits.
`.*` is any length of anything.

https://3v4l.org/nY1aM